# Visual Studio 2012: Component dll failed to load unable to start program

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 for months now and never experienced a problem. But today when i try to run a program i get the error :

> Error while trying to run the project: Unable to start porgramm 'C:\Users\...\EinfacherDelegate.exe'. A
>   component dll failed to load. Try to restart this application. If
>   failures continue, try disabling any installed add-ins or repair
>   installation

From Programs and Features (Control Panel) I repaired Visual Studio 2012 but the problem still remains. When I go to the project folder i can't find any dll files, I see the .exe file which is running correctly if I double click on it. From the error description i don't even know what dll is missing. Any ideas what i could do to solve the problem ? About what dll is visual studio talking ?

Navigating to the executable file manually and running it works. The error above is produced when I press the "Run" button in VS2012.

---

[image: A Component dll failed to load]

---

[image: the dependency walker]

[Here are two files](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3izq5feSjH_d3VFRmlwTnVYcFE/edit?usp=sharing) with the output from dependency walker.

How can i find all these dll files ? And why are they suddenly missing from my Visual Studio 2012 when everything was working fine ?

---

I also tried **sfc /scannow** and it restored some corrupted files, but it did not solve the problem with visual studio.

---

I am not sure if this is normal but when i open a .cs file from my project and click on run in Visual Studio i get the massage:

[image: Unable to Connect Remote Debugging]

---

Comment: Trace such issues with Depends.exe: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the help. But should i put the visual studio ,that is devenv.exe  or the .exe file from my project ?

Comment: try **sfc /scannow** to detect and restore missing system files.

Comment: I wonder if your AV has blocked the files. Does it work if you disable your Anti Virus (if safe to do so)?

Comment: @magicandre1981 i did that too but the problem remains.

Comment: @DaveRook i will try that too and report back. I am using Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: @Devid When you say "run a program", do you mean VS won't load or that running a program in debug mode won't work? If so, does it run in release mode?

Comment: @DaveRook running a program in debug or release mode won't work.

Comment: you might be able to find the DLLs on [dll-files.con](http://www.dll-files.com/)

Comment: please post the complete depends.exe output

Comment: @magicandre1981 ok i uploaded the files. I have put them on my google drive for download.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with new projects? Can you create a new console application, leave it as is, and run in debug mode to see if it compiles?

Comment: @DaveRook yes, that is one of the first things i did. I made a new project in Visual Studio but when i click on run button i get the error that some component dll failed to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other people experiencing similar have said (although this quote is for VS2010)

`"...removed the .suo; .ncb; and user project file, then restarted the solution and it fixed the problem for me."`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864520/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-cannot-find-the-file)

---

Reinstallation

---

If the problem is with running a program in debug mode, then there is a [KB article/fix for this](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=303067). The details of this fix are copied here as well

> Resolution 1
> Right-click the Project Name in Solution Explorer, and then click Properties.
> In the left pane of Properties, click to select Configuration Properties.
> Click to select Debugging.
> In the right pane, click to select the Unmanaged code debugging check box.
>
> Resolution 2
> In Microsoft Notepad, open Boot.ini, which is located in the System Drive folder (usually C:). This file may be hidden and read-only, so you may have to use dir /ASH to find it.
> Remove all of the following switches, if found in the file:
> /debug
> /debugport
> /baudrate
>
> Restart the computer, start Visual Studio .NET, and then debug.

---

Change the Target Framework from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4".

---

This could be down to your Anti Virus blocking access to certain files! You could try it without the AV running.

---

Since it just happened, then I will suspect an update of some sort has occurred which has upset it. Roll back the system (system restore)!

---

Either way, I'm sorry but I can't give any real explanation as to why it would just happen.

Comment: I am trying the first solution before i move to the next solution you suggested, but i can't find a file with .ncb ending in my project.

Comment: @DaveRock nothing happens everything remains the same. I have removed the .suo file and the user project file but i still get the same message that a dll could not run. I will move on with the next solution.

Comment: @DaveRock Windows is started normally and not in debug mode so the second solution is not for me. I am now looking how to stop the Microsoft Security Essentials but i have only the option to stop real time protection. I will do that too and report back.

Comment: Also, what happens if you open your References folder in your project? Do any of them show they're not recognized?

Comment: @DaveRock after the repair i tried to uninstall Visual Studio Ultimate completely but at some point I again get the message that a .dll file could not be found or is missing and therefore Visual Studio could not uninstall completely. I have no References folder in my Project folders. Do you mean in Visual Studio the option under Project Add Reference ? I can't perform a system restore, but i was thinking to upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 8.

Comment: Well, I think a re-install of the OS *should* fix all. In VS, under a project you should have a folder called References. Expand this and make sure there are icons to indicate an error/issue.

Comment: Under the project i can't find the folder References, this might be the problem.

Comment: @Devid What happens if you try to add a new reference?

Comment: @DaveRock i get the error: Package: 'ReferencePackageManager' failed to load.

Comment: I am not sure but i suspect the the NuGet package manager is causing the problem.

Comment: @Devid, try this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO2X3hZfpW8

Comment: Also, lots of details on Google for search phrase *Package: 'ReferencePackageManager' failed to load*

Comment: @DaveRock i did the thing in the video, also i checked google but nothing solved the problem. I will now upgrade to Windows 8 and see if the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search I could not find out why Visual Studio was not working, so I decided to uninstall it completely and then install it again. At first there where also problems uninstalling it because of some missing .dll files. But i figured out that i need first to disable and then uninstall all the plugins in Visual Studio first. Now everything is working fine after I re-installed Visual Studio. I guess the problem was caused by a visual studio plugin (maybe NuGet Package Manager) but i am not sure.